# Jensen-Shannon divergence similarity with different probability space

Tags: probability-distributions, jensen-inequality

I want to quantify the similarity between two probability mass functions (pmf) *p* and *q*, where *q* was noised with a function that changes the probability space of *q*. For instance if the following pmfs are given: the original distribution *p* = [(0,0.5),(1,0.25),(2,0.25)] and the noised pmf *q* = [(0,0.5), (2,0.25)], where in *(x,f(*x*))*, *x* is a value which can be generated, and *f(x)* is the probability of generating x.

Is it possible to calculate the similarity of these pmfs with the JS-divergence? Is it possible to expand the noised pmf *q* by inserting the value (1,0), so that both pmfs have the same support again?

Comment: I don't know Jensen-Shannon (thank you for introducing it to me), but do you that another similarity measure is obtainable via Kolmogorov Smirnov distribution ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.